# Involutions in $\operatorname {PSO}(4,K)$

Tags: finite-groups, algebraic-groups, involutions, classical-groups, centralisers

In the algebraic group $G=\operatorname {PSO}(4,K)$ where $K$ is an algebraically closed field of an odd characteristic, how many different classes of involutions are there and what are the representatives and the centralizer structure?

I've got three classes with representatives
$$
 e_1=\left[ 
\begin{pmatrix}
    w & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & w^{-1} & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & w & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & w^{-1} \\
\end{pmatrix} \right]$$ where $w$ is of order 4 in $K$;
$$
 e_2=\left[ 
\begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \right]$$;
$$
 e_3=\left[ 
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \right]$$

The centralizer in $G$ is $C_G(e_1) =T_2.2^2$, $C_G(e_2) =C_G(e_3)=(A_{1}T_{1}).2$.

Any confirmation or inputs are appreciated.

Comment: Since $G$ is of adjoint type, it is the direct product of its simple subgroups, so $G$ is isomorphic to ${\rm PGL}_2\times{\rm PGL}_2$. There is a unique conjugacy class of involutions in ${\rm PGL}_2$ (given by $z_0=\alpha^\vee(\sqrt{-1})$ in terms of the simple coroot). So there are three involutions in the direct product: $(z_0,1)$, $(1,z_0)$ and $(z_0,z_0)$.

Comment: The centralizer can also be computed easily, and it confirms your calculations. Note that for a simple group of adjoint type, the conjugacy classes of semisimple elements of finite order are classified in terms of the affine Dynkin diagram, by a famous theorem of Kac (see Ch.s 6-8 of his book "Infinite dimensional Lie algebras").

Comment: Thank you for the input. Could you elaborate on the notation for $z_0$?

Comment: In ${\rm SL}_2$, $\alpha^\vee(t)$ is the diagonal matrix with entries $t,t^{-1}$. So we take the image in ${\rm PGL}_2$ of the diagonal matrix with entries $\sqrt{-1},-\sqrt{-1}$.